# Select all possible tuples from a vector in R

Tags: r, set, tuples, stata

I'm trying to write a program in R that when, given a vector, will return all possible [tuples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuples) of elements from that vector.

For example:
tuples(c('a','b','c')) = c('a','b','c'); c('a','b'); c('a','c'), c('b','c'); c('a'); c('b'); c('c')

I think it should return a list of vectors.

For reference, here is a [program that does a similar function in Stata](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456797.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `combn`:

```
x <- 1:3
unlist(lapply(x, function(n) combn(x, n, simplify=FALSE)), recursive=FALSE)
```

Comment: @Zach, in the general case where x can be of any class, you can treat this as working on the indices of x, and then use the result to index x. X_orig <- c('a','b','c'); x <- seq_along(X_orig); xi <- (above); lapply(xi, function(i) X_orig[i])

Comment: no need for that. `x <- letters[1:3]` and then you do the lapply over `1:length(x)`. Works just as fine.

Comment: This answer doesn't generate what it is desired . It generate more tuples than it should !